# Get next file in the folder

Tags: c#, file, directory, system.io.directory

When you open a picture in Windows Photo Viewer, you can navigate backward and forward between supported files using arrow keys (next photo / previous photo).

The question is: how to get path of the next file given path of the current file in the folder?

Comment: I'm pretty sure under the covers it is a list of all files in the folder and then it is a matter of taking the next item in the list. I'm guessing that because it would not be very efficient to query file system every time

Comment: get all the paths into a collection,add a counter starting from 0  and increment/decrement the counter to get next/previous path.

Comment: It's going to be a pretty slow process if the folder contains large number of files, isn't it? Maybe there's another designated way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily by getting all paths into a collection and keep a counter.If you don't want to load all file paths into memory you can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and `Skip` method to get next or prev file.For example:

```
int counter = 0;

string NextFile(string path, ref int counter)
{
    var filePath = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Skip(counter).First();
    counter++;
    return filePath;
}

string PreviousFile(string path, ref int counter)
{
    var filePath = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Skip(counter - 1).First();
    counter--;
    return filePath;
}
```

Ofcourse you need some additional checks, for example in `NextFile` you need to check if you get to the last file, you need to reset the counter, likewise in the `PreviousFile` you need to make sure counter is not `0`, if so return the first file etc.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach of calling `EumerateFiles` with `Skip`, for each file in the directory. This will be extremely inefficient, specially for directories with large number of files.

Comment: This doesn't seem efficient, and this doesn't answer how should we start at middle of list, as when user open an image at middle of a folder..

Answer (score 1):

Given your concern with large number of files in a given folder, and desire to load them on demand, I'd recommend the following approach -

(Note - The suggestion of calling `Directory.Enumerate().Skip...` in the other answer works, but is not efficient, specially so for directories with large number of files, and few other reasons)

```
// Local field to store the files enumerator;
IEnumerator<string> filesEnumerator;

// You would want to make this call, at appropriate time in your code.
filesEnumerator = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath).GetEnumerator();

// You can wrap the calls to MoveNext, and Current property in a simple wrapper method..
// Can also add your error handling here.
public static string GetNextFile()
{
    if (filesEnumerator != null && filesEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        return filesEnumerator.Current;
    }

    // You can choose to throw exception if you like..
    // How you handle things like this, is up to you.
    return null;
}

// Call GetNextFile() whenever you user clicks the next button on your UI.
```

**Edit:** Previous files can be tracked in a linked list, as the user moves to next file.
The logic will essentially look like this -

1. Use the linked list for your previous and next navigation.
2. On initial load or click of `Next`, if the linked list, or its next node is null, then use the `GetNextFile` method above, to find the next path, display on UI, and add it to the linked list.
3. For `Previous` use the linked list to identify the previous path.

Comment: how are you planning to get previous file?